# TSQL inline case inside select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query

```
select item_name from some_table
```

sometimes item_name is a 'sometext' value that I want to replace with item_id column.
I want a functionality similar to isnull, but insteat of null it should be a 'sometext'.

someting like this:

```
 select ISTEXT(item_name,'sometext',item_id) from some_table
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT item_name = CASE WHEN item_name = 'sometext' THEN item_id ELSE item_name END
```

Comment: SQLServer 2012 supports [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) logical function as shorthand way for writing a CASE expressions. `SELECT IIF(item_name = 'sometext', item_id, item_name)`